# Draw an Image stretched on x-dimension?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have a `UIImage` which has a frame of

```
(0,0,100,100)
```

now I want to draw this image into a frame of size

```
(0,0,120,100)
```

I want that the image get stretched. But I don't want to stretch certain parts of the image. I want that the all point are involved. The whole image should be stretched proportionally.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here are your options when it comes to setting the `contentMode` of your view.

I just shamelessly searched for `uiview contentmode` on Google Images.

[image: contentMode]

Comment: And how can I draw my image in the new Rect?

Comment: Just as @ABakerSmith pointed out in the comments to your question: are you using a UIImageView to display the image? In which case you should change the contentMode to .AspectFill or .AspectFit, depending on how you want the image to look.

Comment: No I just want to draw in in a new UIImage first with the new frame.